# Errors in using predict with randomForest in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest

*Note: After lots of experimenting with the code, I have completely re-written this question*

I'm trying to use user-input values in a 1-row data object to predict the user's category with `randomForest`, however I get an error indicating NA/Inf values of my data object.

I have a `randomForest` classifier, which I've trained on a taining dataset and validated on a validation dataset. This was done in my file `analysis.R` on github and the object is saved as `rf.rds`, which is read in by `server.R`).

In `server.R` I read in the training data which is called `x` (i.e. `x.rds`) and then extract only the first row into `userdf`.

In `ui.R` I let users enter values which reactively update this object:

```
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- userdf
  newEntry <- observe({
      values$df$bron_badges <- input$bron_badges
      values$df$silv_badges <- input$silv_badges
      values$df$gold_badges <- input$gold_badges
      values$df$reputation  <- input$reputation
      values$df$views       <- input$views
      values$df$votes       <- input$votes
  })
```

This appears to work. I say so because I can run:

```
output$table <- renderTable({data.frame(values$df)})
```

and watch the values update beautifully in my UI.

*However*, when I try to run the following code to run a prediction for the user I get an error message saying that there are NA's:

```
  output$results <- renderText({
                      {  ds1        <- values$df 
                         x          <- x[,sort(names(x))] 
                         ds1        <- ds1[,sort(names(ds1))] 
                         names(ds1) <- colnames(x)
                         predict(rf, newdata = data.frame(ds1))
                      }
                      })
```

Even though I "know" the data is not `NA` from having watched `values$df` update via `ui.R` in the line mentioned above and by virtue of the fact that all of the initial values which come from `x` are not `NA`. I've also tried it without the `data.frame` part of the `predict` statement.

Interestingly, if I replace the `predict` statement above with `table(is.na(ds1))` it tells me that all 1,033 values are `NA`.

Also interesting, if I replace `ds1` with `userdf` in the `predict` statement, then everything runs fine (`userdf` is the non-reactive object).

If I replace the `predict` statement with `setdiff(colnames(x), colnames(ds1))` it does not show any mis-matching column names (it did until the addition of the `colnames` statements above, due to some weird conversion of `_` to `.` in the reactive dataframe's colnames).

Finally, I find that if I access the names from `rf` via `rf$forest$ncat` I get "`incorrect number of dimensions`" as my error:

```
  output$results <- renderTable({
                      {  ds1        <- values$df 
                         cn         <- rf$forest$ncat
                         cn         <- cn[,sort(names(cn))] 
                         ds1        <- ds1[,sort(names(ds1))] 
                         names(ds1) <- names(cn)#x #rf$forest$xlevels
                         predict(rf, newdata = data.frame(ds1))
                      }
                      })
```

However, with the following modification:

```
  output$results <- renderTable({
                      {  ds1        <- values$df 
                         cn         <- as.data.frame(t(rf$forest$ncat))
                         cn         <- cn[,sort(names(cn))] 
                         ds1        <- ds1[,sort(names(ds1))] 
                         names(ds1) <- names(cn)#x #rf$forest$xlevels
                         predict(rf, newdata = data.frame(ds1))
                      }
                      })
```

My error goes back to "`variables in the training data missing in newdata`".

**Minimal, reproducible example**: https://github.com/hack-r/troubleshooting_predictor_minimal

Here's the full reproducible code and data: https://github.com/hack-r/coursera_shiny

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your example hardly seems minimal. This will help isolate the error. Have you got this working outside of Shiny?

Comment: It works fine outside of `shiny`. I'll see if I can make a more minimal version tonight, but this is pretty much the single purpose of this `shiny` app and I'm not sure what's causing the bug, so this is almost as minimal as I can go.

Comment: @JohnPaul It was just a guess really. I tried it with `reactive` instead of observe, but that just led to output that literally printed the `predict` statement.

Comment: If you want to write into val$res should you be using the global assignment <<-?

Comment: @Hack-R 1)Once you make something a `reactiveValues` it is already reactive, so you don't to wrap stuff in the`newEntry` or `runmodel` `observers`.  2) Your error could be due to different column names used in `userdata()` and the data you used to get `rf`. What was the code you used to get `rf` originally?

Comment: @JohnPaul I have experimented with many different ways of writing this and have completely re-written the question to reflect some things I've found. Could you have another look at it?

Comment: @MrFlick I have created a whole new, clonable github repository with an absolutely minimal version of this error/app. Please have a look.

Comment: When I replace the `predict` line with just `ds1` and change the render command to `renderTable` it does not produce an error **but** also nothing shows up in the `outputTable` output. It just disappears. Same thing for `class(ds1$votes)`...

Comment: @Hack-R  What is going on with the `colnames` statement? It appears that you first give a `data.frame` to `ds1`, but then overwrite them with a character vector using `ds1<-colnames(x)` Is that what you want or do you just want `ds1` to have the same names as `x`?

Comment: What's with the `ds1 <- colnames(x)` line? That is replaceing the data.frame `ds1` with a character vector. Take that out and the predict should work. The newdata= parameter needs to be a data.frame.

Comment: @JohnPaul @MrFlick  aaah!! That was supposed to be `names(ds1) <- colnames(x)` because the column names were mysteriously having their underscores (`_`)replaced with dots (`.`) at some point. I will try that correction right now, thanks for catching it! Update: just fixing that by itself resulted in no output. I also tried wrapping it in `data.frame`. I will correct that part of the question though, thanks.

Comment: I also just tried commenting out the `colnames` lines all together and tried both `renderText` and `renderTable`.

Comment: Ok, 1 more thing try making it `ds1<-isolate(values$df)` and see if that gets you anywhere ( I don't think it will update but it shoudl shown up).

Comment: @JohnPaul Interesting...  so when I do that it goes back to telling me that variable names in the training data are missing in the newdata -- which was happening before but was solved with the `colnames` statements -- but when I `renderPrint` on `setdiff(colnames(ds1), colnames(x) )` it tells me `character(0)`

Comment: @JohnPaul It said `character(0)` again. When I do the `isolate` with `predict` it gives me the same error about missing variables regardless of if I use `renderTable` or `renderPrint`

Comment: Sorry I meant do `renderTable` on `ds1` not the prediciton to make sure you have the correct data.

Comment: correction: That works if there's not an isolate statement but the table disappears if there is an isolate statement.

Comment: @JohnPaul @MrFlick I find that I get "incorrect number of dimensions" as my error if I do `cn         <- rf$forest$ncat`, `cn         <- cn[,sort(names(cn))]`, then `names(ds1) <- names(cn)`...

Comment: Any resolution to this problem Hack-R? I'm having the exact same issue and thought I'd check before creating a new question.

Comment: @LiamFlynn Sorry it's been so long I don't remember but I do think I got it fixed. Have a look at the code on my GitHub repo and you may be able to fix your problem